# Removing notification causes crash

Tags: android, notifications

I am having trouble removing an existing notification. I have looked through other posts and don't see what I am doing wrong.  Here is the code to set it

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    int id = (int) ((long) rowId);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .setContentText(notificationContent)
    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
    .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setTicker(notificationTitle)
    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
}
```

Here is where I try to remove the notification:

```
public void cancelnote(long mRowId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id = (int) mRowId;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Log.e(TAG2, "changed to id" + id);
    notificationManager.cancel(id);


}
```

This is where it crashes.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

This is the error log

```
05-20 11:00:12.364: W/dalvikvm(3159): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414e6438)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:101)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.opd247.OPD247.ReminderCancel.cancelnote(ReminderCancel.java:28)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.opd247.OPD247.meds.onContextItemSelected(meds.java:191)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2592)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.opd247.OPD247.meds.onMenuItemSelected(meds.java:157)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3859)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:193)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:934)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1268)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3059)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3950)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-20 11:00:12.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the `getApplicationContext()` from the line. This works fine for me -

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. Still crashes at that line even without the getApplicationContext()

Comment: But what is the error now? It cannot be the same error right?

Comment: now it says : E/AndroidRuntime(11748): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:423)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

This worked for me ...